# Access two sites hosted on my IIS server with the same port?

Tags: iis, iis-7, webserver, hosting, windows-server-2008

I currently have two websites hosted on my IIS 7 server. Each website has its own host name but shares the same port (80).

Everything **works great locally** to access the two sites:

**Site #1:** http://localhost/ -> http://arcadiastudio.ch

**Site #2:** http://webService.ch/

**But from the outside I cannot** reach my second website hosted on the same port. I do not know what to put in the URL:

**Site #2:** http://arcadiastudio.ch/??

Here is what I have in my host file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       webService.ch
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be very simple. All you need to do is to have each hostname specified in your hosts file. In your case, your host file on your local PC should look like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       webService.ch
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       arcadiastudio.ch
```

And the hosts file on your remote PC should look like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
<remote_ip>     webService.ch
::1             localhost
<remote_ip>     arcadiastudio.ch
```

Obviously, you need to change `<remote_ip>` to the IP address of your web-server.

Also, if you want to allow **any** remote PC to connect, you will need to register your domain names for DNS - you can't edit every host file in the world!!

Comment: Yeahh. Super. Thank you so much! One last question. If I link my second site with a different port. I can to get to on my second site like this: http://arcadiastudio.ch:8080/WebService/ and so I do not need to register a second domain name!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but in order to tell your PC that `arcadiastudio.ch` can be found at IP `www.xxx.yyy.zzz` you will need either a hosts file entry, or a DNS entry for that domain name. The port is not actually relevant in this circumstance.